# Discord Bot doesn't respond | Tenor API

Tags: python, api, discord.py, bots

I have a discord bot and I wanted to upgrade the `gif` command so I watched a video by the coding train (In which he made a bot in JS) and I tried to implement it in python. Discord.py is async so I could'nt use requests but instead I used aiohttp which is asynchronous. I watched another video which was for discord.py but in which the YouTuber didn't use the tenor API. I have tried to change some stuff so it works with tenor but it still won't work. I haven't worked with APIs that much so I don't know if this is just a simple fix:

This is the command only:

```
@client.command(name='gif',aliases=['randomgif','randgif'])
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
async def gif(ctx,*,search_term:str=None):
    if not search_term:
        await ctx.send("Please put at least one argument more into the command.")
    else:
        URL = f"https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q={search_term}&key={TENORKEY}&contentfilter=high"
        async with request("GET", URL, headers={}) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                data = await response.json()
                content = data['results']
                gifUrl = content['url']
                await ctx.send(gifUrl[random.randInt(0, len(content))])
                print(gifUrl[random.randInt(0, len(content))])
            else:
                ctx.send(f"Server returned {response.status}.")
```

Best thanks in regards :)

Comment: Try debugging it by adding `print()` between the lines to see where it fails

Answer (score 1):

`content` is a list of objects. One object per gif.

Use `randint` to generate a random index and then you can access the `url` key and send the value.

```
gifUrl = content[random.randint(0, len(content))]['url']
await ctx.send(gifUrl)
```

Comment: you could simply use `random.choice` instead